# python : signature matching aws s3 bucket

Tags: python, amazon-s3

I have a s3 bucket with a file in it and while retrieving file from s3 bucket, I want to check if it is retrieved from the source I am expecting from and not from some man-in-the-middle thingy. What is the best way to do that? Something with Authentication header may be or associate with key?

Answer (score 0):

You use HTTPS.

SSL certificates not only serve as a public key for encryption, they are also signed by a trusted certificate authority and confirm that the server you intended to contact possesses a certificate (and has the correlated private key) that matches the hostname you used when you made the contact.  A properly-configured client will refuse to communicate over HTTPS with a server presenting a certificate with a mismatched hostname, or a certificate signed by an untrusted/unknown certificate authority.

Comment: HTTPS is fine and says that it is from trusted source. I was thinking of encrypting the file AES256 and then decrypting it on client side may be java , python? Just to confirm it is kind of from the same source.

Comment: Yes, you could, although that technically only proves that it's from a source in possession of the symmetric key.  For that matter, you could do the same thing with negligible effort using S3's [Server Side Encryption with Customer-Managed Keys](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ServerSideEncryptionCustomerKeys.html) (SSE-C).  S3 does the AES 256 encrypt before storing and decrypt before download, and the uploader and  downloader must both submit the key with the request (over https, of course).  S3 uses the key but does not store it.